# When should I change a SerialUID?

Tags: java, serialization

I have a bunch of serialized classes.  Normally I have generated serial UIDs for all of them as the Java rules are rather restrictive and recreate Serial Numbers with basically any change.  But this lead me to the question, that I haven't been able to find an answer for in the internet:

When does it make sense to break backwards compatibility and manually change the Serial Version UID in the class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Section 5.6 of the Java Spec helps here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html#6678

5.6 Type Changes Affecting Serialization

> With these concepts, we can now describe how the design will cope with
>   the different cases of an evolving class. The cases are described in
>   terms of a stream written by some version of a class. When the stream
>   is read back by the same version of the class, there is no loss of
>   information or functionality. The stream is the only source of
>   information about the original class. Its class descriptions, while a
>   subset of the original class description, are sufficient to match up
>   the data in the stream with the version of the class being
>   reconstituted.
>
> The descriptions are from the perspective of the stream being read in
>   order to reconstitute either an earlier or later version of the class.
>   In the parlance of RPC systems, this is a "receiver makes right"
>   system. The writer writes its data in the most suitable form and the
>   receiver must interpret that information to extract the parts it needs
>   and to fill in the parts that are not available.

5.6.1 Incompatible Changes

> Incompatible changes to classes are those changes for which the
>   guarantee of interoperability cannot be maintained. The incompatible
>   changes that may occur while evolving a class are:
>
> - Deleting fields - If a field is deleted in a class, the stream written will not contain its value. When the stream is read by an
>     earlier class, the value of the field will be set to the default value
>     because no value is available in the stream. However, this default
>     value may adversely impair the ability of the earlier version to
>     fulfill its contract.
> - Moving classes up or down the hierarchy - This cannot be allowed since the data in the stream appears in the wrong sequence.
> - Changing a nonstatic field to static or a nontransient field to transient - When relying on default serialization, this change is
>     equivalent to deleting a field from the class. This version of the
>     class will not write that data to the stream, so it will not be
>     available to be read by earlier versions of the class. As when
>     deleting a field, the field of the earlier version will be initialized
>     to the default value, which can cause the class to fail in unexpected
>     ways.
> - Changing the declared type of a primitive field - Each version of the class writes the data with its declared type. Earlier versions of
>     the class attempting to read the field will fail because the type of
>     the data in the stream does not match the type of the field.
> - Changing the writeObject or readObject method so that it no longer writes or reads the default field data or changing it so that it
>     attempts to write it or read it when the previous version did not. The
>     default field data must consistently either appear or not appear in
>     the stream.
> - Changing a class from Serializable to Externalizable or vice versa is an incompatible change since the stream will contain data that is
>     incompatible with the implementation of the available class.
> - Changing a class from a non-enum type to an enum type or vice versa since the stream will contain data that is incompatible with the
>     implementation of the available class.
> - Removing either Serializable or Externalizable is an incompatible change since when written it will no longer supply the fields needed
>     by older versions of the class.
> - Adding the writeReplace or readResolve method to a class is incompatible if the behavior would produce an object that is
>     incompatible with any older version of the class.

5.6.2 Compatible Changes

> The compatible changes to a class are handled as follows:
>
> - Adding fields - When the class being reconstituted has a field that does not occur in the stream, that field in the object will be
>     initialized to the default value for its type. If class-specific
>     initialization is needed, the class may provide a readObject method
>     that can initialize the field to nondefault values.
> - Adding classes - The stream will contain the type hierarchy of each object in the stream. Comparing this hierarchy in the stream with the
>     current class can detect additional classes. Since there is no
>     information in the stream from which to initialize the object, the
>     class fields will be initialized to the default values.
> - Removing classes - Comparing the class hierarchy in the stream with that of the current class can detect that a class has been deleted. In
>     this case, the fields and objects corresponding to that class are read
>     from the stream. Primitive fields are discarded, but the objects
>     referenced by the deleted class are created, since they may be
>     referred to later in the stream. They will be garbage-collected when
>     the stream is garbage-collected or reset.
> - Adding writeObject/readObject methods - If the version reading the stream has these methods then readObject is expected, as usual, to
>     read the required data written to the stream by the default
>     serialization. It should call defaultReadObject first before reading
>     any optional data. The writeObject method is expected as usual to call
>     defaultWriteObject to write the required data and then may write
>     optional data.
> - Removing writeObject/readObject methods - If the class reading the stream does not have these methods, the required data will be read by
>     default serialization, and the optional data will be discarded.
> - Adding java.io.Serializable - This is equivalent to adding types. There will be no values in the stream for this class so its fields
>     will be initialized to default values. The support for subclassing
>     nonserializable classes requires that the class supertype have a
>     no-arg constructor and the class itself will be initialized to default
>     values. If the no-arg constructor is not available, the
>     InvalidClassException is thrown.
> - Changing the access to a field - The access modifiers public, package, protected, and private have no effect on the ability of
>     serialization to assign values to the fields.
> - Changing a field from static to nonstatic or transient to nontransient - When relying on default serialization to compute the
>     serializable fields, this change is equivalent to adding a field to
>     the class. The new field will be written to the stream but earlier
>     classes will ignore the value since serialization will not assign
>     values to static or transient fields.

Answer (score 3):

Never. You should organize yourself so that classes have the same serialVersionUID for their entire lifetime. You should (a) resist serialization-incompatible changes to the class; (b) write your own readObject()/writeObject()/readResolve()/writeReplace() objects so as to preserve the initial serialization format, and define an explicit serialVersionUID right at the beginning of the class's lifetime. The instant you change this value you have an *enormous* headache on your hands. Plan to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

From [the JavaDoc of the Serializable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html):

> The serialization runtime associates with each serializable class a version number, called a serialVersionUID, which is used during deserialization to verify that the sender and receiver of a serialized object have loaded classes for that object that are **compatible with respect to serialization**.

I think this is a good hint to answer your question: As soon as you change the class in a way, that serialization is affected (like adding/removing/changing serialized class members), then you really should change the value of `serialVersionUID`.

Comment: So then adding a method call, should not have any effect.  I should worry about non-transient field changes mostly.

Comment: Changing the class by adding or reordering members is benign. See the Object Serialization Specification, Versioning section. No need to change the serialiVersionUID. If you read Sun's documentation the idea is *nver* to have to change it.